# Was man judged at the cross along with Satan and the rebellious Angels?

Tags: exegesis, new-testament, eschatology, judgment

In Matthew 5:22 Jesus says that anyone who calls another a fool will be in danger of Hell fire

Matthew 5:22  KJV

> But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger
> of the judgment: and whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council:
> but whosoever shall say, Thou fool, shall be in danger of ***hell fire***.

and in the Revelation Chapter 20:14 it tells us that Death and Hell will be thrown into the lake of fire:

Revelation 20:14  KJV

> And ***death and hell*** were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

Also in the story about Lazarus and the rich man:

Luk 16:22 through 24  KJV

> 22 And it came to pass, that the beggar died, and was carried by the angels into Abraham's bosom: the rich man also died, and was buried;
>
> 23  And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.
>
> 24  And he cried and said, Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus, that he may dip the tip of his finger in water, and cool my tongue; for I am ***tormented in this flame***.

Apparently some go to Hell when they die and are tortured by the heat (fire) and at the Great White Throne judgment are then thrown into the lake of fire.

Revelation 20:15  KJV

> And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was cast into the ***lake of fire***.

Revelation chapter says nothing about either ***Satan, His minions being judged*** only thrown into the lake of fire.

It does say that the dead are judged but only **for their works**:

Rev 20:12 and 13  KJV

> 12 And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of life: and the dead were ***judged out of those things which were written in the books, according to their works***.
>
> 13  And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which were in them: and ***they were judged every man according to their works***.

Does it seem possible that unbelief is judged along with Satan and his minions at the Cross, and the Great White Throne judgment is for what wrongs they have done on Earth?

Comment: You assume that Satan and the other rebellious angels were judged at the cross, but I'm not aware of the Bible teaching that, or aware of any Christian positions which do too. My understanding has always been that they are judged at the final future judgement described in Revelation.

Comment: @ curiousdanni I am taking the liberty of quoting from the answer given by Trober to this question.As for Satan, he's been judged: John 16:11. KJV
Of judgment, because the prince of this world is judged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mankind was not judged at the cross.  Rather, judgement *began* - and per that, for the household of God, not mankind en masse.

As for Satan, he's been judged, Jn 16:11.  But, the sentence has yet to be carried out, Rev 20:2.  He will get a temporary brief from that incarceration, Rev 20:7.  Then, have a permanent sentence carried out, Rev 20:10.

Back to mankind, judgement has *now begun* with the household of God, 1 Pt 4:17.  The scripture's "household of God" can be *loosely* interpreted as "Christians" today.  However, keep in mind mainstream religion is not a *spiritual* body, rather an institution of man, e.g. Matt 13:24-30, I Cor 10:5-6, Rev 17 and more.

The rest of mankind that is not "the household of God" has not entered into judgment, Rev 20:5.  They will enter into judgement later, Rev 20:12.

The reference you make to Luke 16:22-24 does not support the poor man died then went to heaven immediately.  To make that assertion, one would have to throw out the *explicit* references in scripture that is *not* the case, e.g. Heb 11:39-40, Jn 6:44, 54, I Cor 15:51-52.

(Many also use Lk 23:43 in the same context.  There is no punctuation in the original Greek.  We *know* the criminal on the cross is not in heaven per the scriptures above, among many, many more).

So, one one's dying and going to heaven, or hell, upon the *first* death.  That's *explicitly* not the case in scripture.  (And, popularity of a belief makes it no more true, scripture is the final authority).

So, in conclusion: judgement *began* - for a part of mankind, the "household of God" with the cross.  The rest of mankind enters into judgement later.  Satan is on his own "judgement plan" with God.  (And, there's a fourth category, 1 Cor 6:3 concerning the judgement of angels).

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Not bad for a first post!  This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: @ Trober Please expand your answer, as it is stated I am unable to determine if you are saying that Christians are being judged now, or whether you are saying that man is being judged now and must face another judgment at the great white throne judgment, which is an entirely different concept than my question. My question was has man's belief been judged at the cross and he faces a different judgment at the Great white throne, and your concept if I understand it correctly is that man is judged before death.

Comment: Will do.  I'm new to the site and reviewing the material David Stratton referenced above.  But, will do shortly (today).

Comment: @David Stratton - I'll have to chew on "references showing ... who teaches/believes it". For now, I stuck with scripture references and one common belief anyone familiar with Christianity will experience: going to heaven or hell immediately upon death.  I've read the material you mentioned, but it left me with questions.  Probably the meta site is the place to take that if I continue with the web site.  I'm not sure if the mission statement of this web site is clear, or if meant for believers, non-believers, or both.  (And, the analogy on Democrats and a Republican are spot-on IMHO).

Comment: @ Trober Thank you for an excellent answer, should you, and I hope you will, continue to use this site your answers will be much better if when you cite a reference you include the verbiage. That prevents the necessity of stopping to look up your reference, thus it becomes a tedious task to jump back and forth from your answer to the Bible. Again thank you and welcome to the site.

Comment: @ Trober I have taken the liberty of proposing an edit to your answer to make it easier to understand and reformatted to recommended format and also added the verbiage for your references. Hope you don't mind. it was such an exceptional answer.

Comment: @CecilBeckum: editing, not a problem. I'd rather have a more helpful answer than "my" answer. :-)   As for including the "verbiage", you mean the scriptures?  On purpose I didn't do that.  Reason: someone truly interested will do that; it's easy for many to just read and move on w/o the additional effort.  ;-)   (With today's online bibles, one can cut-n-paste the book/chapter/verse and have the scripture in 2 seconds.  I use this: bible.cc).

Comment: @ Trober The reason we do that here is that not all of our readers may have access to a Bible to look up the Scriptures. Websites are accessible from most of the world.